# Embedding an instagram/youtube page in an iframe "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Tags: javascript, youtube, instagram, x-frame-options

I realize that there are ways to embed youtube videos directly, that's not what I would like to do. Is there any way to display the site in an iframe? Or instagram? This is crucial for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you give us the URLs you are trying to embed?

Comment: that is irrelevant, the question explains well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, otherwise the header would be quite useless. Of course you can use a really old browser that does not recognize the header but there is nothing you can do about it server side. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Alright I didn't think so, I was just looking for a hackish way to get around it. Thanks anyways.